# Combining Functionality in a Single CMD Prompt

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

Right now, due to installing various commandline programs, I've got 3 different modified CMD prompts that I use during development.

One handles git and all of its functionality.
One handles Mono
And one handles PostgreSQL

And I can see myself adding more to the stack later on.

Is there a way to combine the functionality of all of these into a single cmd prompt?

I think the fact that Git runs out of a .bat file instead of the standard CMD.exe + PATH modifiers is what makes this tough.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably be able to do this by just modifying your environment variables.  Go to Control Panel → System → Advanced → "Environment Variables..." to configure them.

I use Git (msysgit) from an unmodified command prompt. All it requires are these environment variables:

```
EDITOR=Notepad.exe
PATH contains C:\path\to\Git\cmd
GIT_SSH=C:\Path\to\Plink.exe      (for GitHub)
```

I believe the only thing the Mono command prompt needs is for your PATH to contain Mono's \bin folder, and PostgreSQL needs its installation path there as well.

Try adding these variables, then open a new command prompt and see if it works as expected.  Be careful, especially when modifying PATH, since this can have far-reaching implications.  If your PATH currently looks like:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
```

Be sure to only add on to the end of it:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Mono\bin;C:\Path\to\PostgreSQL
```

Answer (score 0):

All these CMDs are basically invocations of the same old cmd.exe thru bat files, who set all sort of environmental variables.

You do need these bat files, which can change with the installation of new versions.

So, in my opinion, there is no magic solution.
To make the bat files more available, you can copy the shortcuts to the desktop (or elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but you can use [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) to make them tabs within the same window.  I usually get rid of all the toolbars apart from the tab bar.

[image]